# How can I make sure that a recursive call to a function is what I think it is?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I make sure that a recursive call to a function is what I think it is?

For example, suppose that I have:

```
def foo(x):
    if x <= 1:
        return
    foo(x - 1)
```

How do I ensure that the innermost nested `foo` is the same as the outermost caller? Technically, the innermost nested `foo` is referring to `foo` in `globals()`. The original `foo` can become accidentally shadowed sometime later. The risk is especially high if it has a very short commonly used function name such as:

- `pprint` (for "pretty print")
- "debug"
- "sanatize"
- "clean"
- etc..

An example which shows why this is sometimes a problem is shown below:

```
# scroll down until you get to the text which says `BEGIN`
# just ignore the code until then...

import sys 
wes = string.whitespace.replace(" ", "") # white except space   
remove_white = lambda stryng, *, re=re, string=string, wes = wes: re.sub('[' + wes + ']', '', stryng)    
# keep scrolling down... to `BEGIN`   
_print  = lambda *args, strm=sys.stdout.write, end="\n",: strm(' '.join(
        (remove_white(str(arg).strip()) for arg in args)
    ) + end)
# ______  _____  _____  _____  _   _ 
# | ___ \|  ___||  __ \|_   _|| \ | |
# | |_/ /| |__  | |  \/  | |  |  \| |
# | ___ \|  __| | | __   | |  | . ` |
# | |_/ /| |___ | |_\ \ _| |_ | |\  |
# \____/ \____/  \____/ \___/ \_| \_/
# 
# okay you can stop scrolling now!                                   
#
def foo(beer_count):
    beer_count = float(beer_count)
    print(beer_count, "bottle(s) of beer on the wall!")
    if beer_count <= 1:
        return
    foo(beer_count - 1)

_print("begin everything working okay.\n", 40*"#")
foo(4)
_print(40*"#", "end everything working okay.")

_print("\n\nbegin \u00B00o NIgHtMaRe o0\u00B0\n", 40*"#")
foo_alias = foo
foo = lambda beer_count: print(beer_count**0.5, "bottle(s) of beer on the wall!")
foo_alias(4)
_print(40*"#", "end \u00B0nIgHtMaRe\u00B0 \n\n")
```

How can a programmer prevent `foo` from being shadowed... **err** ... maybe not "**prevent**" it per say, but deal with it?

My best attempts are abject failures:

```
import inspect
def foo(x):
    if x <= 1:
        return
    ########################################
    frame  = inspect.currentframe()
    framer = inspect.stack()[0]
    try:
        print("this is the function name, not a reference to the actual function:", framer.function)
    finally:
        del frame
    ##########################################
    foo(x - 1)

foo(10)
```

The following doesn't work either...

```
def foo(x):
    if x <= 1:
        return
    foo.f(x - 1)
foo.f = foo
```

Comment: If you accidentally shadowed the name of a function you were using, that's a bug no matter how that function refers to itself, and you need to fix the bug. Even if `foo` makes sure it's always calling the right `foo`, anything *else* that needs to call `foo` is going to have the same problem.

Comment: You're thinking about how to make sure `foo` always uses the right `foo`, when you actually need to make sure *everything* always uses the right `foo`.

Comment: There's a fine line between [defensive and overly defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming). This here seems to fall into the latter category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a callable object instead of a function?

Something like:

```
class Recurser:
    def __call__(self, n):
        if n <= 1:
            print('.')
        else:
            print('.', end='')
            self(n-1)
recurse = Recurser()
recurse(4)  # ....
b = recurse
b(4) # ....
def recurse(n):
     print('OH NO')
b(4) # ....
```

Or, for your example:

```
class BeerCounter:
    def __call__(self, beer_count):
        beer_count = float(beer_count)
        print(beer_count, "bottle(s) of beer on the wall!")
        if beer_count <= 1:
            return
        self(beer_count - 1)
foo = BeerCounter()
```

Nightmare averted.

Comment: While this works well, it throws up a lot of questions for anyone reading this code…

Comment: @deceze: Comments ;-) `# This is a functor so that it still works if assigned to a different name`

Answer (score 1):

Lets start by simplifying your example

```
def foo(beer_count):
    print(beer_count, "bottle(s) of beer on the wall!")
    if beer_count <= 1:
        return
    foo(beer_count - 1)

foo(4)
print('-----')
foo_alias = foo
foo = lambda beer_count: print(beer_count**0.5, "bottle(s) of beer on the wall!")
foo_alias(4)
```

which gives

```
4 bottle(s) of beer on the wall!
3 bottle(s) of beer on the wall!
2 bottle(s) of beer on the wall!
1 bottle(s) of beer on the wall!
-----
4 bottle(s) of beer on the wall!
1.7320508075688772 bottle(s) of beer on the wall!
```

If you instead keep the recursive element within its own scope

```
def foo(beer_count):
    def bar(beer_count):
        print(beer_count, "bottle(s) of beer on the wall!")
        if beer_count <= 1:
            return
        bar(beer_count - 1)
    return bar(beer_count)
```

then you get your required outcome.

---

Clarification from resulting comment thread:

This is still an unusual and likely unnecessary defensive action.  In general, anyone who is modifying code in the same global scope as you is one of:

- Developing the code with the intention of making it work
- [Monkey-patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) the code to make it fit their use case
- Debugging or experimenting

If you are developing this is probably overly defensive.  It is a nice habit, but it is uncommon in python compared to other (e.g. functional) languages and may confuse or distract the reader.  The duplication issue is easily caught with static checkers (e.g. pylint's `redefined-outer-scope`).

If someone is monkey-patching, they have the responsibility to make their own changes work, and there isn't any onus on the original developer to support that use case.  If anything, it would be better for them to ask for that feature to be built in.

In the case of debugging and experimentation, as with monkey-patching, the budding scientist should know they are likely to shoot themselves in the foot, and be watching for it.  There are many ways to break a program, but they should be able to determine what they have done themselves in most cases, since the delta will be small, and if they can't it is their own fault =).

Comment: Yes, but you've really just localised the point of failure more. You haven't *prevented* the problem from occurring outright, as you could still reassign `bar` inside `foo` and get the same problem. The likelihood of that rises with the complexity and length of the function. So it's really the same issue as before, just somewhat dampened down. Which is to say, this is probably overly defensive to begin with.

Comment: @deceze on the contrary, this prevents the problem described from occurring because it encapsulates the recursion.  There is no global reference to `bar` being made here, so it cannot be partially hijacked - you can only redefine `foo` to something else entirely.

Comment: Again, you can still accidentally reassign `bar` ***inside `foo`***. In the code written inside `foo`. Before: you could accidentally reassign `foo` anywhere within the entire module. Now: you could accidentally reassign `bar` within `foo`. Same problem, just more localised.

Comment: I think I follow but your argument is somewhere between tautological and specious =/.  You're saying that if you write it wrong, it wont work - I agree.  I'm saying if I write it in this way correctly, no one can monkey patch me into failure (which does happen, and which I presume OP is asking about).  This will continue to work: `import you; you.orig = you.foo; you.foo = NotImplemented; you.orig(X)`

Comment: Yeah, pretty much my argument is: if you write it wrong, you gonna have errors. So how much self-defence do you really need to practice? I might rather employ a static type checker or such to discover such issues, or let them surface at runtime. It's a bug that needs to be fixed by altering the source code anyway, it's not a runtime error that you need to anticipate and defend against. Arguably you're hiding accidental reassignment of `foo` with this, which should probably be an error.

Comment: I like this approach too, +1. It has the side benefit that input validation and quick exits can be put in the outer frame, avoiding checks in all the recursive calls.